# Formatting a double as a string correctly in C#?

Tags: c#, string, formatting, double

I want to print out the string represenation of a double without losing precision using `ToString()`  I get the following when I try formatting it as a string:

```
double i = 101535479557522.5; 
i.ToString(); //displays 101535479557523
```

How do I do this in C#?

Answer (score 9):

If you want it to be exactly the same you should use `i.ToString("r")` (the "r" is for round-trip). You can read about the different [numeric formats on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Comment: after i add mor numbers again it neglect the .5 !!

Answer (score 5):

You're running into the limits of the precision of Double. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx):

> Remember that a floating-point number can only approximate a decimal number, and that the precision of a floating-point number determines how accurately that number approximates a decimal number. By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

If you want more precision - and particularly maintaining a decimal representation - you should look at using the `decimal` type instead.

Comment: failed again if we add 33845159852507.5 5 times the result will be 169225799262538 not 169225799262537.5 i think it is big problem

Comment: @salamonti: This answer explains why you are seeing the results you are seeing. *ALL* programming languages have this “problem” — it’s an unfortunate limitation of reality that you can only have so much precision within a 64-bit value.

Comment: @salamonti: Exactly what Timwi said, basically. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx for more information.